# How to find the direct (inductive) limit of any directed system?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, category-theory, modules

I'm trying to grasp the definition of direct limit of a directed system. For this, I checked some references including Bourbaki but could't get the idea completely. I want to know exactly how to find the direct limit if I'm given a directed system; though Bourbaki gives some details for this but I could't understand from it. If someone recommend me some good references ...

Secondly, does the direct limit (if it exists) posses all those properties which the objects of a given category contain?

Comment: In generally no, Direct limit of finite groups May not be finite. Please check this.https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/notes/DirectLimits.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiyha7siJbnAhWMxzgGHbwrAtYQFjAQegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2uRlPCM3jFddG3oKgn8EZj

Comment: One possible place to start: if all the maps in the directed system are inclusion maps (in some concrete category), then the direct limit is essentially the union.  Then, if all the maps in the directed system are injective, you can think of the direct limit as being a generalized union.

Comment: You view colimits as gluing objects. More precisely, colimits could be [realized](https://mathoverflow.net/a/229103/20948) as coproducts and coequalizers.